# How to get first date and last date of the week from week number and year?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JavaScript I want to get first date of the week and last date of the week by week number and year only.

For example if I my input is:

`2(week),2012`

Then my output should be:

`2012-01-08 and 2012-01-14`

Comment: How about if I give 2 for year 2013? What should it return?

Comment: it should return the second week of the first date and last date....

Comment: @balaphp actually it will return first and last date of 2nd week of the year 2013..m i right. ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var year = 2012;
var week = 2;
var d = new Date("Jan 01, " + year + " 01:00:00");
var w = d.getTime() + 604800000 * (week - 1);
var n1 = new Date(w);
var n2 = new Date(w + 518400000)

console.log(n1);
console.log(n2);
```

n1 contains the first day of the week
n2 contains the last day of the week

As for the constants:
604800000 is one week in milliseconds
518400000 is six days

Comment: Incorrect, n1 is not necessarily the monday and n2 is not necessarily the sunday.

Comment: `new Date("Jan 01, " + year + " 01:00:00")` is a poor way of creating a Date for 1 January as it relies on built–in parsers with an unsupported string format. Setting the hour to 1 seems unnecessary. `new Date(year, 0)` is shorter and much preferred. Milliseconds in 1 day, week, whatever aren't consistent where daylight saving is observed.

Answer (score 6):

A little change to @bardiir 's answer,
if the first day of the year is not Sunday(or Monday) that result is not correct.
You should minus the number of the first day.

Changed code

```js
firstDay = new Date(2015, 0, 1).getDay();
console.log(firstDay);
var year = 2015;
var week = 67;
var d = new Date("Jan 01, " + year + " 01:00:00");
var w = d.getTime() - (3600000 * 24 * (firstDay - 1)) + 604800000 * (week - 1)
var n1 = new Date(w);
var n2 = new Date(w + 518400000)

console.log(n1.toString());
console.log(n2.toString());
```

if you wish the first is Sunday, change `(firstDay-1)` to `firstDay`

Comment: `new Date("Jan 01, " + year + " 01:00:00")` is not sensible as it relies on the built–in parser and an unsupported format. `new Date(year, 0)` is equivalent, reliable and less to type. Not all days are 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed, so results may be wrong occasionally. This answer also assumes week numbering starts from 1 Jan, which in many cases it doesn't, and returns weeks like Tue 5 Apr  2022 to Mon 11 Apr 2022.

Answer (score 1):

you can check and try with below link.

[How to get first and last day of the week in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210376/get-first-and-last-day-of-the-week-in-javascript)

It will may helpful to you.

Thanks.

Comment: i had checked it already.. its returning values by date but i want same results by week number and year...

Answer (score 0):

Change previous answers and make it clear. @bardiir

```js
// give the year and week
let year = 2021;
let week = 1;

// first date of year
let firstDateOfYear = new Date(year, 0, 1);
// get the day of first date in the year
let firstDayOfYear = firstDateOfYear.getDay();
console.log("first day of year", firstDayOfYear);

let timeofOneDay = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000;
let timeofOneWeek = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 1000;
// last day of the week, 6 days later
let timeof6Day = 60 * 60 * 24 * 6 * 1000;

// if week start from Monday
let timeOfFirstDay = firstDateOfYear.getTime() - (timeofOneDay * (firstDayOfYear - 1)) + timeofOneWeek * (week - 1);
let timeOfLastDay = timeOfFirstDay + timeof6Day;
console.log("week start from Monday");
console.log(new Date(timeOfFirstDay).toString());
console.log(new Date(timeOfLastDay).toString());

// if week from Sunday
timeOfFirstDay = firstDateOfYear.getTime() - (timeofOneDay * (firstDayOfYear - 0)) + timeofOneWeek * (week - 1);
timeOfLastDay = timeOfFirstDay + timeof6Day;
console.log("week start from Sunday");
console.log(new Date(timeOfFirstDay).toString());
console.log(new Date(timeOfLastDay).toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   dt = new Date();
   var firstDateOfWeek=(dt.setDate(dt.getDate()-dt.getDay()));
   var lastDateOfWeek=(dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+6-dt.getDay()));
```

Answer (score -1):

The powerful way is for this issue, is to use moment.js

```
let date=new Date();
let start_date = moment(date).startOf('date').toDate()
let end_date = moment(date).endOf('date').toDate()
```

Comment: Momentjs is [depreciated](https://momentjs.com/docs/) and should use an alternative library such as [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/).