# How to get first day of current year in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need javascript code to get first day of year. e.g. It will be 1st Jan 2013 for this year.

For next year it should be 1st Jan 2014. So basically 1st day of whatever is current year.

Comment: answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803151/how-to-get-first-day-and-last-day-of-the-week-number-and-year

Comment: You mean on what day does jan-1st fall?

Comment: Lots of info on the Date() object: 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

Comment: So you basically need to find the year? Because I'm pretty sure 01/01 is always the first day. Unless it's the day of the week you're looking for?

Comment: var targetDate = new Date();
targetDate.setDate(1);

// So you can see the date we have created
console.log(targetDate);

Comment: It's really simple:  let date = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1);

Answer (score 174):

Create a new `Date` instance to get the current date, use `getFullYear` to get the year from that, and create a `Date` intance with the year, month 0 (January), and date 1:

```
var d = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1);
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: Would you please add a 'var' before 'd'? I cannot edit it because 'var' is only three characters.

Comment: This solution gives me the last day of the previous year `2019-12-31T23:00:00.000Z`. This gives me the first day: `new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1, 1)`

Comment: @WatermelonSugar: The code in the example produces a date in the local time zone, but you show a date in UTC, so the difference may come from how you display the date.

Answer (score 13):

```js
var year = 2013;

var date = new Date(year, 0, 1);

console.log(date); // Tue Jan 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)
```

You can construct Dates using `new Date(YEAR,MONTH,DAY)`

So giving the constructor the `year` you want and the first Day of the First Month, you get your Date Object

*Note that the Date Object starts counting with 0 for the Month, so January == 0*

Answer (score 5):

Try this one:

```
var timestmp = new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1);
var yearFirstDay = Math.floor(timestmp / 86400000);
var day = new Date(yearFirstDay);
alert(day.getDay());
```

Note: that code returns number, so Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

```
var d = new Date(2013, 0, 1).getDay(); //0 is January for some reason

alert(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hM36f/)

```
year = prompt("Enter year : ");

d = new Date(year, 0,1);

var myDays=["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];

alert("First Day is " + myDays[d.getDay()]);
```