# js Get first day of week by week number and year

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Could you tell me what is the best way to get first day of week by week number and year?

I using this code from  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803151/how-to-get-first-day-and-last-day-of-the-week-number-and-year?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
function getDateOfWeek(week, y) {
   var d = new Date("Jan 01, "+y+" 01:00:00");
   var w = d.getTime() + 604800000 * (week-1);
   var n1 = new Date(w);
   var n2 = new Date(w + 518400000);
   return {
            dateFrom:n1,
            dateTo: n2
    }
}
```

**getDateOfWeek(1,2017)** returning dates: **01.01.2017, 08.01.2017**

but need : **02.01.2017, 08.01.2017**

**getDateOfWeek(53,2016)** returning dates: **30.12.2016, 05.01.2017**

but need : **26.12.2016, 01.01.2017**

Can you have some idea how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to **offset for `day of the week`**

```js
function getDateOfWeek(week, y) {
  var d = new Date("Jan 01, " + y + " 01:00:00");
  var dayMs = (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  var offSetTimeStart = dayMs * (d.getDay() - 1);
  var w = d.getTime() + 604800000 * (week - 1) - offSetTimeStart; //reducing the offset here
  var n1 = new Date(w);
  var n2 = new Date(w + 518400000);
  return {
    dateFrom: n1,
    dateTo: n2
  }
}
console.log(getDateOfWeek(1, 2017));
console.log(getDateOfWeek(53, 2016));
```

Comment: @Daria Thanks, please upvote and accept (you have already done) the answer that helps you so that it helps other as well.