# Show Previous and next week dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 buttons( Previous and next ) for week. In between the previous and next week button needs to show week ending date (Fridays) for that week.
I want to display previous week date from Sun 11/18 to Mon 11/26 when we click the previous week button. Same as the next week button click event to show from Mon 11/26" to Sun 12/2.
How it possible to show? and how to take the week ending date (Fridays) for that week?

Comment: post some codes what you've tried. It'll be helpful to solve

Comment: if you are working with button, why you tag `php`...?? don't you know `php` is a server side language...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This's to get the date in 7 days, and from 7 days ago:

```
var today = new Date();
var nextWeek = Date.parse(new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + 7));
var previousWeek = Date.parse(new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 7));
```

If you don't want a timestamp returned, remove the `Date.parse()` from it to receive a string like this:

```
Mon Dec 03 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (West-Europa (standaardtijd))
```

(This was returned on a system with Dutch language settings)

To get the week dates, take a look at these 2 questions:
[JavaScript - get the first day of the week from current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156434/javascript-get-the-first-day-of-the-week-from-current-date)
[How to get first and last day of the week in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210376/get-first-and-last-day-of-the-week-in-javascript)

Comment: Hey I just print nextWeek on alert. It output like "1354473000000"

Comment: that's timestamp you need to convert it to whatever format you like.

Comment: Okay. Suppose I want the previous week of the date 11 th Nov. The how to take it?

Comment: Pass the date as [IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamp](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#page-14) to the [Date object (example)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Examples)
So: `var today = new Date('Nov 11, 2012');`, or, in this format: `new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond])` with the parameters between brackets being optional.

Comment: We get next week like Mon Dec 03 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST). Then how to take next 7 days to print like (mon to sun)

Comment: Did you take a look at the 2 links I provided in the answer?

Comment: var previousWeek = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 7);
var previousWeekSplit = previousWeek.split(" ");
alert(previousWeekSplit[0]);

Comment: Sir, I cant use the split method with this. Can tell me the reason?

Comment: Yes, `previousWeek` is a date object, not a string. You can do: `previousWeek.toString().split(" ");`, or, use one of the `get` methods from the [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods)

Comment: If u don't mind.. Can u give me ur mail id? So I can ask ma doubts directly :)

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of StackOverflow as community / support site.