# How to get first date and last date from Previous week in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

Please anyone share the code to find the previous week's first date from current date in JavaScript. For example, if the current date is 19th dec 2012, I should get 10th Dec 2012 and last date 16th Dec 2012  as result.

Comment: Who says a week starts on Monday?

Comment: i want to monday to sunday get previous week.

Comment: it seems like it has already been answered several times on this site.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210376/get-first-and-last-day-of-the-week-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
function getPreviousSunday()
{
var today=new Date();
return new Date().setDate(today.getDate()-today.getDay()-7);
}


function getPreviousMonday()
{
var today=new Date();
if(today.getDay() != 0)
  return new Date().setDate(today.getDate()-7-6);
else
  return new Date().setDate(today.getDate()-today.getDay()-6);
}
```