# Get other week days for a given date jquery

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a date in `2016-07-21` format. I want to get this week's other date(from Sunday to Saturday).

```
Ex. from `2016-07-17` to `2016-07-23`.
Want to get all other week dates-2016-07-17, 2016-07-18, 2016-07-19, 2016-07-20, 2016-07-22, 2016-07-23 
If i pass '2016-07-18' then need to get 2016-07-17, 2016-07-19, 2016-07-20,  2016-07-21, 2016-07-22, 2016-07-23
```

How can i achieve this using jquery ?
Can anyone help me to do this?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get first and last day of the week in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210376/how-to-get-first-and-last-day-of-the-week-in-javascript)

Comment: not Sunday and Saturday.. Want to track all other week days when pass a particular date

Comment: Have a look at this to get dates between a range: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413590/javascript-get-array-of-dates-between-2-dates

Comment: Thank you @Alilshaq.. I got it