# How to dynamically get the start and end date of the week

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic framework.Is there a way to dynamically get the start and end date of the week when user selects a random date.

Comment: Any code? Please  post your tries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210376/how-to-get-first-and-last-day-of-the-week-in-javascript) I've made a configuration based on your needs. The code is in vanilla js but you can easily translate it to angular code, since functionality is the same.

The function to find the first and last day of the week, based on user selected date:

```
function getFirstLastDayOfWeek(userDate) {

  let result = {};

  let curr = new Date(userDate); // get current date
  let first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
  let last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6

  result = {
        firstDay:new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toUTCString(),
    lastDay:new Date(curr.setDate(last)).toUTCString()
  };

  return result;
};
```

And here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s7c30mrj/2/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var days=new Date().getWeek();
console.log(days[0].toLocaleDateString() + ' to '+ days[1].toLocaleDateString())
```

Dynamic date

```
var days=new Date("10/01/2017").getWeek();
    console.log(days[0].toLocaleDateString() + ' to '+ days[1].toLocaleDateString())
```

Answer (score 0):

Please mention your ionic version.

Using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) would solve your problem easily.

Lets say you have a random date with you and wants to find [start of week](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/).

```
moment(<randomDate>).startOf('isoWeek');
```

End of the week

```
moment(<randomDate>).endOf('isoWeek');
```

Comment: I'm using ionic version 1