# Get the Start Date and the End date of the current week using jquery

Tags: jquery

how to get the start date and end date of the current week using jquery?

for example, today is 03/18/2019 and for this week the start date is (03/18/2019) and the end date is (24/18/2019), I have seen [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5210450), but I want the minimal code to express this function, Note that the week starts on Monday and ends on sunday

Comment: Have you try anything?

Comment: Good question, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: yeah I've seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/5210450 but I want to write less code

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210376/how-to-get-first-and-last-day-of-the-week-in-javascript

Comment: kindly, read what i've asked i have already written that i have seen this code, but i want less code to express the concept

Comment: you should share your code.

Comment: it's not my code but the requirement from the link you posted is different from mine, i'm seeking a start day monday and ending day sunday

Comment: okay , so that's your concern.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var today = new Date;
var first_date = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate())).toUTCString();
var last_date = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + 6)).toUTCString();

console.log('First Day :', first_date);
console.log('Last Day :', last_date);
```

Find This Small snippet form :https://stackoverflow.com/a/5210450/10866052

Comment: it returns sunday is the first day of the week, but the right answer is monday

Comment: Improved Now,please check

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you :

```
<script>
var curr = new Date;
var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(curr.getDate())).toUTCString(); 
var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate((curr.getDate())+6)).toUTCString();
</script>
```

Comment: okay, i have seen such code but i want to write less code

Comment: @AhmadMM Updated my answer

Comment: you've copied it from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13190874, it returns sunday is the first day and saturday is the last day of current week

Comment: @AhmadMM updated my answer