# How to filter HTML data based on date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, filter

Let's expect I have a table with a lot of rows. The rows data is from server.

```
<table>
  <tr data-date="${date}"> // let's assume this is from server
    <td>Code</td>
    <td>${date}</td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-date="${date}>
    <td>Code</td>
    <td>${date}</td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I also have 3 buttons that look like this:

```
<button>currentday</button>
<button>currentweek</button>
<button>currentmonth</button>
```

I want when one of the buttons have the class active for example, to show in the table the only rows with the corresponding date. Let's assume I pressed day, then I show in my table the rows that have the `data-date` matching the `data-date` of the day `button`. And if I press week or month, I check all the table rows `data-date` that are in between the week or month (that match).

Comment: what corespond date should be shown exactly? the buttons only say the words "day" "week" and "month", so which date is the corresponding one?

Comment: day is Today's date, week is the first and last day of week, month is the first and last day of month.

Comment: I would recommend to look into a data-binding framework. That makes operations like this much easier.

Comment: what do you mean, is the value of the button being controlled by some other code? when it says "day" "week" "month" in the question, does it mean some other value that corresponds to that? can you post an example of what such a generated outcome is?

Comment: example would be the `button` day for example, with a data attribute that holds a function which returns the current day like this: `<button data-date="${getCurrentDay}">day</button>`, which then I compare the pressed button's data attribute with the table data and show the corresponding data.

Comment: @Dipzera but the innerHTML always says `day` no matter what day it is?

Comment: @bluejayke of course, you clicked day, you get table data for today. you clicked week, table shows data for the entire week, and so on.

Comment: oh now I'm starting to understand, got it, working on answer...

Comment: @Jonathan I need this to get done with Vanilla JS :(

Comment: I only do vanilla JS :)

Comment: In that case you could link a rebuild table function to the buttons that filter on date. Make sure to keep all the data from the server in a separate object.

Comment: @Jonathan why keep the data from the server in a separate object?

Comment: Or in the table, just hiding and showing the rows. Whatever you prefer.
Just keep in mind that if you start parsing the dates in your HTML all kinds of bad things will happen depending on different browsers and timezone settings.

Comment: I also have a status filter, like `All, Rejected, Accepted, Pending`. I've done it by hiding and showing the rows.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that:

> 1. "day" means todays date,
> 2. "week" means date range since first to last day of current week
> 3. "month: means date range since first to last day of current month

So if today is 2020-07-02:

> 1. day would give "2020-07-02"
> 2. week would give range 2020-06-29 (if monday is first day of week) to 2020-07-05 (if sunday is last day of week)
> 3. month would give range 2020-07-01 to 2020-07-31

In JavaScript, according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210376/how-to-get-first-and-last-day-of-the-week-in-javascript)

```
let currentDate = new Date(); //returns todays date

currentDate.getDate() // returns day of current month
currentDate.getDay() // returns day of current week (sun = 0, mon = 1)

let firstDayOfCurrentWeek = currentDate.getDate() - currentDate.getDay()
let lastDayOfCurentWeek = firstDayOfCurrentWeek + 6; // assuming, sunday is first day of week

firstDayOfCurrentWeek = new Date(currentDate.setDate(firstDayOfCurrentWeek ));
lastDayOfCurentWeek = new Date(currentDate.setDate(lastDayOfCurentWeek));
```

Its much easier to get range of first and last day of month:

```
let firstDayOfMonth = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), 1); 
let lastDayOfMonth = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth() + 1, 0);
```

You need to mark cells containing dates somehow:

```
<table id="mytab">
  <tr>
    <td>Code</td>
    <td class="date">02-07-2020</td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Code</td>
    <td class="date">25-06-2020</td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, when you have all required dates for your buttons, simply read date from your table cells and check which ones matches range, and hide the rest.

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytab");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {

    if (col.classList.contains("date")) {
        let control_date = col.innerHTML.split('-');

        control_date = new Date(control_date [2], control_date[1] , control_date[0]);

        if (control_date == currentDate) {
            //this cell date is todays date

        }
        
        if (control_date > firstDayOfCurrentWeek && control_date < lastDayOfCurentWeek) {
            //this cell date is in this week date
        }

        if (control_date > firstDayOfMonth && control_date < lastDayOfMonth) {
            //this cell date is in this monthdate
        }

    }
   }  
}
```

Please note, that date can match more than one range eg. todays date will match today, wee, and month at the same time

Answer (score 0):

When it's said it's supposed to "show in the table the elements with the corresponding date.", I assume that means there is a table, AKA some table HTML sent from the server and stored as a string (or variable) somewhere with all of the possible dates,  and I'm also guessing that the buttons are used to somehow select a specific date, I'm imagining a calendar-style app, where there is a current day shown, and one can change the week by click on the week button, etc., but let me know if this is something else.

Anyways the main point of the question is "how to filter HTML data based on date in javascript", by "html data" I assume that means to show and hide certain HTML, based on the innerHTML value of some of the elements contents.

To do that, you need to start with the value you are searching for. For example, let's use the string "02-07-2020", generated one way or another, and you have an entire table of dates, I'm assuming you received the string of this table from the server and have it stored in JavaScript, if not them I'm assuming the server sent back the raw HTML onto the page and you want to JavaScript to filter the HTML table (AKA remove all rows that don't correspond to the string) when a button is pressed. Either way it should be the same.

So assuming there is a table with all of the dates already in HTML, and you want to "hide" (/I'm assuming that means remove) all cells whose contents **don't** correspond with the date, then you have a couple different options.

Either, you can manually call the [deleteCell()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_tablerow_deletecell.asp) method on all of the cells that don't contain the value, (but then you would have to regenerate all of those cells that DO contain the next value anyways) or you can generate the entire table with JavaScript on each button press, and only generate the cells you want, or the most preferred option (which I assume you're asking about anyways) is to add `display:none` to the style of the surrounding `tr` elements, the only problem is how to find what specific data to filter through, but this should be trivial.

Ok so we're going to go with the 3rd method, and to do this we simply need 3 inputs, we need what `day` we're searching for, what `week`, and what `month` (I assume, as mentioned in the comments, that `day` means the full date, `week` means a particular week only, and `month` means an entire month, so each one is less inclusive than the last, so we also need a variable input to tell us which one we are searching for).

OK so basically we just need to supply two main inputs into our function, a start date and an end date, and if there is no end date, assume we are looking for only the start date

So I'm in america so I'm used to american dates, but it seems from the question that it is using the european format, with the day before the month, so that will complicate our use of the built in `Date` API a bit, but it should still be fine, we just need to either manually make our own proto-date system to check if one string is in between two others, or extract the day-week-month from the string using `.split(-)` and generate a new string or use with the native `Date` API, but either way it should work out.

OK so let's get started:

```js
doIt.onclick = () => {

  var startDate = dateStart.value,
        endDate = dateEnd.value;
  sortThroughTable(startDate, endDate)
 
};

function sortThroughTable(start, end) {
  Array.apply(0, myTable.rows).forEach(x => {
    var cells = Array.apply(0, x.cells);
    var secondCell = cells[1].innerText;
    var isHidden = shouldItBeHidden(
      secondCell,
      start, end
    );
    if(isHidden) {
      x.style.display = "none"
    } else if(x.style.display == "none")
      x.style.display = "";
  })
  
  function shouldItBeHidden(
    cellTxt,
    start,
    end
  ) {
    var parsedCell = myParse(cellTxt),
        parsedStart = myParse(start),
        parsedEnd = myParse(end);
    return !(
    //here's where the real logic is
      parsedCell ? 
        (parsedStart && parsedEnd) ?
          isDateGreaterOrEqual(parsedCell, parsedStart) &&
          isDateGreaterOrEqual(parsedEnd, parsedCell)
        : 
          parsedStart &&
            cellTxt == start
      : false
      
    )

  }
  
  function isDateGreaterOrEqual(parsedDate, otherParsedDate) {
    var isYearGreater = (
      parsedDate.year >
      otherParsedDate.year
    ),
        isMonthGreater = (
      parsedDate.month >
      otherParsedDate.month
    ),
        isDayGreater = (
      parsedDate.day >
      otherParsedDate.day
    ), 
    
        isYearSame = (
      parsedDate.year ==
      otherParsedDate.year
    ),
        isMonthSame = (
      parsedDate.month ==
      otherParsedDate.month
    ),
        isDaySame = (
      parsedDate.day ==
      otherParsedDate.day
    );
    
    if(isYearGreater) {
      return true;
    } else if(isYearSame) {
    
     if(isMonthGreater) {
        return true;
     } else if(isMonthSame) {
     
        if(isDayGreater) {
          return true;
        } else return isDaySame;
        
     } else return false;
     
    } else return false;
  }
  
  function myParse(str) {
    return (splat => 
      splat.length == 3 &&
      !splat.find(x => isNaN(x)) ? 
      Object.fromEntries(
        (list => splat
          .map((x, i) => (
            [list[i], parseInt(x)]
          ))
        )([
          "day", "month", 
          "year"
        ])
      ) : null
    )(
      typeof(str) == "string" ? 
        str.split("-")
      : []
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<table id=myTable>
  <tr>
    <td>Code</td>
    <td>02-07-2020</td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Code</td>
    <td>25-06-2020</td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--don't know how 
the library is set up but I'm just gonna 
do it by manually entering the strings to 
an input, you can adapt it to whatever you want
-->

<input id="dateStart" value="24-06-2020">
<input id="dateEnd" value="26-06-2020">

<button id=doIt>filter!</button>
```

Comment: `(I assume, as mentioned in the comments, that day means the full date, week means a particular week only, and month means an entire month, so each one is less inclusive than the last, so we also need a variable input to tell us which one we are searching for).`

Day means current day, today's date. Week means current week, and it's always current week, month is also always current month (first day of month, and last day of month).
Which means there's no need of an input for that. You just take the date returned from the function stored inside the button.

Comment: @Dipzera oh ok didnt get that

Comment: For example, when pressing the day `button` we get the current day's date and compare it to the one's from the table, if it matches we show it. If we press the week `button` we do the same, but we show all the table rows, whom dates are inbetween the first day of week, and last day of week.