# ReactJS -- I want to call setState for every onChnage event to set array empty

Tags: reactjs

```
In ReactJS -- I want to display week calender in my timesheet app !! Weekly timesheet .
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPukx.png
```

I have taken empty array selectWeek[],onChnage event (date changes from date picker), It should always empty array ->selectWeek first then add elements into it as per the code.

Below code onChnage Event, it keeps adding dates to array-selectedWeek !!But on every onChnage event , I want to take empty array Only

Code:
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

```
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
class TimesheetForm extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        var startDate=new Date();
        var today = new Date(),
        this.state = {            
            counter0:0,
            counter1:0,
            counter2:0,
            counter3:0,
            counter4:0 ,
            total:0,
            currentDate: date,
            startDate: startDate,
            currentDay:currentWeekDay,
            week:[],
            selectedWeek:[]
    
          };    

          for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {          
            var first = today.getDate() - today.getDay() + i            
            var day = new 
            Date(today.setDate(first)).toISOString().slice(0, 10)             
            this.state.week.push(day)
          }

          console.log(this.state.week); // gives me an array of all dates of week
        
    } 

handleDateChange = date => {
       
        console.log("selectedWeek"+this.state.selectedWeek);
        console.log(date);
        this.setState({
            startDate: date
          });
             
         for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {          
            var first = date.getDate() - date.getDay() + i ;
            var day = new 
            Date(date.setDate(first)).toISOString().slice(0,10)  ;
             this.state.selectedWeek.push(day);
          }  
          console.log("shiv selectedWeek"+this.state.selectedWeek);
          
      };
    
    increment =(e)=> {
        if(e.target.id==="id0"){
        if(this.state.counter0=== 8){
            this.setState({
                counter0:8
            });       
        }
        else{
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                counter0: prevState.counter0 + 1
            }));

        }      
        }   
        if(e.target.id==="id1"){
            if(this.state.counter1=== 8){
                this.setState({
                    counter1:8
                });       
            }
            else{
                this.setState(prevState => ({
                    counter1: prevState.counter1 + 1
                }));
    
            }      
            }   
            if(e.target.id==="id2"){
                if(this.state.counter2=== 8){
                    this.setState({
                        counter2:8
                    });       
                }
                else{
                    this.setState(prevState => ({
                        counter2: prevState.counter2 + 1
                    }));
        
                }      
                }   
                if(e.target.id==="id3"){
                    if(this.state.counter3=== 8){
                        this.setState({
                            counter3:8
                        });       
                    }
                    else{
                        this.setState(prevState => ({
                            counter3: prevState.counter3 + 1
                        }));
            
                    }      
                    }  
                    if(e.target.id==="id4"){
                        if(this.state.counter4=== 8){
                            this.setState({
                                counter4:8
                            });       
                        }
                        else{
                            this.setState(prevState => ({
                                counter4: prevState.counter4 + 1
                            }));
                
                        }      
                        }    
                        e.preventDefault();
      }
 render(){

        return(
            <form >
               
                <DatePicker
                        selected={this.state.startDate}
                        onChange={this.handleDateChange}
                    />
 <table className="" align="right">
                <tr className="">
                    <td>
        <label>{this.state.selectedWeek[1] ? this.state.selectedWeek[1] :this.state.week[1] }</label>
                        <div>
                            <input
                            className="time-input"
                            type="text"  
                            size="1"                                
                            value={this.state.counter0}
                            />
                            <button id="id0" onClick = {this.increment}> + </button> 
                            <button id="id0" onClick = {this.decrement}> - </button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td className="">
                        {console.log(this.state.week)}
                        {console.log(this.state.selectedWeek)}
        <label >{this.state.week[2] }{this.state.selectedWeek[2]}</label>
                        <div>
                            <input
                            className="time-input"
                            type="text" 
                            size="1"                
                            //onClick={e => e.target.select()}                    
                            value={this.state.counter1}
                            />
                            <button id="id1" onClick = {this.increment}> + </button> 
                            <button id="id1" onClick = {this.decrement}> - </button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td className="">
                        <label >{this.state.selectedWeek[3] ? this.state.selectedWeek[3] :this.state.week[3] }</label>
                        <div>
                            <input
                            className="time-input"
                            type="text"    
                            size="1"             
                            //onClick={e => e.target.select()}                    
                            value={this.state.counter2}
                            />
                            <button id="id2" onClick = {this.increment}> + </button> 
                            <button id="id2" onClick = {this.decrement}> - </button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td className="">
                        <label >{this.state.selectedWeek[4] ? this.state.selectedWeek[4] :this.state.week[4] }</label>
                        <div>
                            <input
                            className="time-input"
                            type="text"  
                            size="1"               
                            //onClick={e => e.target.select()}                    
                            value={this.state.counter3}
                            />
                            <button id="id3" onClick = {this.increment}> + </button> 
                            <button id="id3" onClick = {this.decrement}> - </button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td className="">
                        <label >{this.state.selectedWeek[5] ? this.state.selectedWeek[5] :this.state.week[5] }</label>
                        <div>
                            <input
                            className="time-input"
                            type="text" 
                            size="1"                
                            //onClick={e => e.target.select()}                    
                            value={this.state.counter4}
                            />
                            <button id="id4" onClick = {this.increment}> + </button> 
                            <button id="id4" onClick = {this.decrement}> - </button>
                        </div>                    
                    </td>
                    <td className="">
                        <label >Total:</label>
                        <div>
                            <input
                            className="time-input"
                            type="text"   
                            size ="1"             
                            //onClick={e => e.target.select()}                    
                            value={this.state.counter0+this.state.counter1+this.state.counter2+this.state.counter3+this.state.counter4}
                            />                                                                
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>                     
        </table>
}
}
```

Comment: Please add more details or code that you have done so far.

Comment: I want to use date picker of today's date and display a week view for all day.

Comment: I added setState({selectedWeek:[] }) ;before for loop in onChange function. but it gives me an empty array in render() method where I am printing these array values based on day number [0,6]. That's why, on each OnChange event,I need empty array to set the current week dates only based on the selected date.

Comment: console.log("shiv selectedWeek"+this.state.selectedWeek);  results                        
 1st time when we change date (as array is empty now)    shiv selectedWeek 2020-08-16,2020-08-17,2020-08-18,2020-08-19,2020-08-20,2020-08-21,2020-08-22

Comment: console.log("shiv selectedWeek"+this.state.selectedWeek);  On next onChange event  ,Its appending dates in an array(selectedWeek)  !! Console log:     shiv selectedWeek 2020-08-16,2020-08-17,2020-08-18,2020-08-19,2020-08-20,2020-08-21,2020-08-22,2020-08-23,2020-08-24,2020-08-25,2020-08-26,2020-08-27,2020-08-28,2020-08-29

Answer (score 1):

You can use the third-party library called [flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/getting-started/), where you can find an option to enable to a specific date range.

The config will be something like this

```js
import flatpickr from "flatpickr";


// Set from and to dynamically as per the week
flatpickr(element, { enable: [{ from: "2025-04-01", to: "2025-05-01" }]});
```

You can find more config options [here](https://flatpickr.js.org/options/) use it as per you needs.

Comment: How would I get the date of the current week !! For eg                                                                                              If I select 12/08/2020, then I need to display dates from the start of the week like 10/08/2020 Monday to 14/08/2020 Friday

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210376/how-to-get-first-and-last-day-of-the-week-in-javascript).